# Magento2 How to get the default attribute set id for Customer?

Tags: magento2, eav, customer-attribute, attribute-set, eav-attributes

How to retrieve default attribute set ID for the customer? And also is it possible in the practical scenario to have multiple attribute sets for EAV entity type Customer? I know in the case of entity type product, you can create multiple attribute sets but is it also normal in the case of the customer as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For get default attribute set ID for the customer:

```
$attribute_set_id = \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER
```

Comment: Thanks, could you also please share your opinion about is it normal to have multiple attribute sets for Customer ?

Comment: @ZeeshanKhuwaja Currently as per my thinking and based on code magento2 use fix only one attribute set id for customer.